# Django Validate Form with formset

Tags: django, django-validation

I have a form with a formset.  I'm trying to add custom validation to the form.  The cust_acc_no has to be unique.  However, in my view if form.is_valid() is false I'm getting the following error : local variable 'formset' referenced before assignment.  How can I use the custom validation and display the original form before checking if it's valid?

This is my views.py:

```
def newcustomer(request):
CustomerFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Customer, Customer_contact, fields=('company','contact_name','contact_tel', 'contact_email'), extra=15 )
form = CustomerForm(request.POST or None)
if request.method == 'POST':
    if form.is_valid():

        form_instance = form.save()
        customer = Customer.objects.get(company=form_instance)
        formset = CustomerFormSet(request.POST or None, instance=customer)

        form.save()

        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Formset is invalid")

        return redirect('custlist')
    else:
        form = CustomerForm()
        formset = CustomerFormSet()

else:
        form = CustomerForm()
        formset = CustomerFormSet()


context = { 'form':form,
            'formset':formset
          }
return render(request, 'customers/newcustomer.html', context)
```

This is my forms.py:

```
class CustomerForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = '__all__'

    def clean_cust_acc_no(self):
            cust_acc_no = self.cleaned_data.get('cust_acc_no')

            if cust_acc_no is None:
                raise forms.ValidationError(_("This is unique."))
            return cust_acc_no
```

This is my template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block page_head %}Add New Customer{% endblock %}

{% block navbar %}
<navbar class="mr-auto">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <ul class="nav navbar-expand">
    <li>
    <button type="submit" form="c-form" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Add Customer</button>
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" onclick="document.location='{% url 'custlist' %}'">Close Without Saving</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

</navbar>
{% endblock %}


{% block content %}
<form id="c-form" action="{% url 'newcustomer' %}" method="post">
  {{ formset.management_form }}
  {% csrf_token %}

  <div class="container-fluid ">

    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-6 ">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-3">{{ form.company.label }}</div>
          <div class="col-8" >{{ form.company }}</div>
          <div class="col-1"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-3">{{ form.cust_acc_no.label }}</div>
          <div class="col-8">{{ form.cust_acc_no }}</div>
          <div class="col-1"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-3">{{ form.vat_no.label }}</div>
          <div class="col-8">{{ form.vat_no }}</div>
          <div class="col-1"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-3">{{ form.reg_no.label }}</div>
          <div class="col-8">{{ form.reg_no }}</div>
          <div class="col-1"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-3">{{ form.bus_tel.label }}</div>
          <div class="col-8">{{ form.bus_tel }}</div>
          <div class="col-1"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-3">{{ form.mobile.label }}</div>
          <div class="col-8">{{ form.mobile }}</div>
          <div class="col-1"></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-6 ">
        <div class="row ">
          <div class="col-4">{{ form.addr_1.label }}</div>
          <div class="col-8">{{ form.addr_1 }}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-4">{{ form.addr_2.label }}</div>
          <div class="col-8">{{ form.addr_2 }}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-4">{{ form.addr_3.label }}</div>
          <div class="col-8">{{ form.addr_3 }}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-4">{{ form.addr_4.label }}</div>
          <div class="col-8">{{ form.addr_4 }}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-4">{{ form.statement_email.label }}</div>
          <div class="col-8">{{ form.statement_email }}</div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div>
        <br>
        <br>
          {% include "myformset.html" %}
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  </form>


{% endblock content %}
```

This is myformset.html:

```
<table class="table table-borderless">

  {% for form in formset.forms %}
  {% if forloop.first %}
  <thead class="thead-light">
    <tr>
      {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
      <th>{{ field.label|capfirst }}</th>
      {% endfor %}
    </tr>
  </thead>
  {% endif %}

  <tbody>
    <tr class="{% cycle row1 row2 %}" >
       {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
       <td style="padding: 5px;" align="center" valign="middle">
          <!-- <div class="col-lg-2"> -->
          {# Include the hidden fields in the form #}
          {% if forloop.first %}
          {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
          {{ hidden }}
          {% endfor %}
          {% endif %}
          {{ field.errors.as_ul }}
          {{ field }}
       </td>
       {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I don't see how `formset` is even defined on the initial `GET` page load...

Comment: Sorry for sounding ignorant but I'm new to django.  Are you saying that you cannot see where I have the formset defined in my newcustomer.html template?  I have the form in  myformset.html and I include it at the bottom on newcustomer.html..  I hope that answers your question?

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying.  I have changed my view.  I am no longer getting the error, however, when I submit the invalid form, I get redirected to a blank form again.  My initial values are missing?

Comment: You instantiate `CustomerForm` and `CustomerFormSet` with no args so of course the form is empty.  I'm unclear how you want it to work so I'm not sure how to fix it, but you don't need to redefine `form` again as `form = CustomerForm(request.POST or None)` at the beginning is sufficient.  You need to pass what you want to see in the formset, though.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear.  I want to start with a blank input form.  When the data is entered on the form I want to submit the form and validate the data entered.  If there are any invalid entries I want to form to be redisplayed as entered with the error message of the invalid entries.  Hope this is more clear?

Comment: Your other `CustomerFormSet` instances need a `request.POST or None` so it has the information that's posted.  I'm just not sure what `instance` you'd want in those other cases.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try

Comment: I finally got this right.  Thanks